# Could not active the menu bar using Angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am facing an issue. I am unable active the right menu bar using Angular.js. I have some menu,sub-menu and sub-sub-menu but as per requirement I am unable to active those. I am explaining my code below.

> route.js:

```
var Admin=angular.module('easyride',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);
Admin.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('/',{
        url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .state('dashboard',{
        url:'/dashboard',
        templateUrl:'dashboard.html',
        controller:'dashboardController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.settings',{
        url:'/settings',
        templateUrl:'settings.html',
        controller:'settingsController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.settings.area',{
        url:'/area',
        templateUrl:'area.html',
        controller:'areaController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.settings.area.manageState',{
        url:'/manageState',
        templateUrl:'manageState.html',
        controller:'manageStateController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.settings.area.manageCity',{
        url:'/manageCity',
        templateUrl:'manageCity.html',
        controller:'manageCityController'
    })
})
```

Here actually when user will get into to the inner page by default the `Home` table will active. when user will click on `settings`  menu the respective sub-menu `Manage Area` and `sub-sub-menu Manage State` tab remain active. I am explaining my page below.

> dashboard.html:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <!--<li ui-sref-active="active" ><a ui-sref="dashboard">Home</a></li>-->
              <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="dashboard">Home</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.settings.area')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.settings.area.manageState">Settings</a></li>


            </ul>
          </div>
```

[Here is my full plunkr working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/ECScSrcUecgIpPWVyzrp?p=preview). Here I need when user will click on `settings` menu the respective `sub-menu and sub-sub-menu` will remain active and other will inactive which is not happening in my case. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the example below , How i am activating the sub menu and its menu. I am guessing this may help you.

applying "active" class based on the "stateName" which we get from application controllers from "$state" provider, Based on that i am using ng-class directive to active the menu and its sub-menu.

```
<li uib-dropdown ng-class="{'active':($root.stateName.indexOf('dashboard.settings')>=0)}">
    <a href uib-dropdown-toggle>Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu >
        <li ng-class="{'active':($root.stateName.indexOf('dashboard.settings.area.manageCity')>=0)}">
           <a ui-sref="dashboard.settings.area.manageCity">Manage City</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{'active':($root.stateName.indexOf('dashboard.settings.area.manageState')>=0)}">
            <a ui-sref="dashboard.settings.area.manageState">Manage State</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

And

In your controller files please use the following code to set the stateName.

```
module.registerController('TopicController', function ($state, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.stateName = $state.current.name;//This line in all routes controller.
});
```

Here is an Plunkr link : edited your code.
https://plnkr.co/edit/bFhvod7zf8JgnEAuH6oo?p=preview

You have added the navigation in dashboard page itself so its better you separate the navigation from your actual view.
Please check the above Plunkr.

Comment: In which file I need to change this. Can you please edit this plunkr ?

Comment: Please format your code. Its unreadable. I think you deleted some part.

Comment: No, This is not what I wanted. I have structure like this `Menu->sub-menu->sub-sub-menu`.

Comment: Then you have to mention the same structure what you want in your question first.

Comment: Please check the Plunkr link.

Comment: Ok but while clicked on `settings` the first all child and sub-child menu should open. Here it not happening like this.

Comment: i think you can do it easily. If not tell me that also i will only edit and update the Plunkr .

Comment: Can you please update the plunkr so that I will check ?

Comment: Ok,its working but when click on `manage city` tab the `manage state` tab also remains active. You can check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163702/discussion-between-subhra-and-chiru-adi).